# Get all controllers authorized for user in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm currently working on an ASP.net site where we use an authorize attribute on all of the controllers. Right now the home page gets a list of all of those controllers and few properties and displays them to the user as cards. I'm using reflection to get each controller by looking for an interface I created for each controller. I'm currently trying to figure out how only return the controllers that the user is authorized to use based on the authorize attribute. Is there an easy way to do this?

Here is my current code to get the controllers:

```
static List<IControllerPlugin> controllerplugins = GetSubClasses<IControllerPlugin>()
.Select(type => (IControllerPlugin)Assembly.GetExecutingAssebly().CreateInstance((${type.Namespace}.{type.Name}))
.OrderBy(x => x.ControllerName).ToList();

private static List<Type> GetSubClasses<T>()
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                .Where(cntlrs.IsSubclassof(typeof(Controller)))
                .Where(t => type.IsAssignableFrom(t)).ToList();

    return types;
}
```

Comment: `Where( t=> Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(t, typeof(T)  ).Any() )`

Comment: I should clarify: I want to only pull I want to actually check if the user has access to each controller and only show each controller they are authorized to use

Comment: How is your authorization deciding whether a user has access to a controller?

Comment: We are pulling roles back from a db and each controller has a custom authorize attribute that checks the roles and permissions against some global enums.